# How to create a NamgedRange using google sheets API when doing a batch update with Go

Tags: go, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, named-ranges

I recently started writing a program to export CSV and SQL to google sheets. And in some scenarios I need to create a NamedRange while creating the sheet and/or updating it. The google official documentation is kinda confusion and not very helpful for me. Can anyone please show me an example code or point me in the right direction?

Right now I have something along these lines. This is just sample code to show one of the scenarios.

```golang
    func writeSS(ssid string, content [][]interface{}) {

    ctx := context.Background()

    b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./credentials/client_secret.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
    }

    config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
    }
    client := getClient(config)

    srv, err := sheets.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(client))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Sheets client: %v", err)
    }

    spreadsheetId := ssid

    rangeData := "Sheet name!A1:A6"

    rb := &sheets.BatchUpdateValuesRequest{
        ValueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    }

    rb.Data = append(rb.Data, &sheets.ValueRange{
        Range:  rangeData,
        Values: content,
    })
    _, err = srv.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(spreadsheetId, rb).Context(ctx).Do() //Check this again
    // _, err = srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Update(spreadsheetId, writeRange, &vr).ValueInputOption("USER_ENTERED").Do()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Done.")
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Try to lay it out in the form - I want to do X, I try Y, instead I get Z. Is there an error you are getting? Which documentation you are trying to follow?

Comment: There is no problem, I'm simply trying to get a sample code on how to create a RangedName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a named range using googleapis with golang.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, the method of spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate of Sheets API is used. When you want to create the named range in the existing Google Spreadsheet, please use the method of spreadsheets.batchUpdate.
- In your script, you are trying to put the values to the cells using the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`. I think that an error related to the scopes occurs. In this case, please use the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```golang
config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
}
client := getClient(config)

srv, err := sheets.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(client))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Sheets client: %v", err)
}

spreadsheetId := "###" // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
sheetId := 1234567890 // Please set your sheet ID.
nameOfNamedRange := "sampleNamedRange1" // Please set the name of the named range.

req := sheets.Request{
    AddNamedRange: &sheets.AddNamedRangeRequest{
        NamedRange: &sheets.NamedRange{
            Range: &sheets.GridRange{
                SheetId:          int64(sheetId),
                StartRowIndex:    1,
                EndRowIndex:      3,
                StartColumnIndex: 1,
                EndColumnIndex:   3,
            },
            Name: nameOfNamedRange,
        },
    },
}
requestBody := &sheets.BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest{
    Requests: []*sheets.Request{&req},
}
resp, err := srv.Spreadsheets.BatchUpdate(spreadsheetId, requestBody).Do()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Print(resp)
```

- In this sample script, the gridrange of `StartRowIndex: 1, EndRowIndex: 3, StartColumnIndex: 1, EndColumnIndex: 3,` means the cells "B2:C3".
- When this script is run, the named range of `nameOfNamedRange` is created with the range of "B2:C3" of `sheetId` in the Google Spreadsheet of `spreadsheetId`.

#### Note:

- From your showing script, unfortunately, I cannot know the filename of the file including the access token and refresh token. If the filename is `token.json` used in [the Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/go), before you run the modified script, please delete the file. And, please reauthorize the scopes. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [AddNamedRangeRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addnamedrangerequest)